# EmacsのソースコードをEmacsで関数検索しながら読みたい

Tags: emacs, elisp

Emacsのソースコードを読みたいと思い、C-h kやC-h fで関数を定義しているelispのソースコードにはアクセスできたのですが、
よりコアな部分のC言語で書かれたソースファイルにアクセスしようとしたところ（C-h fで検索してC source codeとリンクが貼られているところに飛ぼうとしたところ）、「The C source window.c is not available」のようになり、ジャンプできませんでした。

Emacsを実装しているCのソースファイルはどこに格納されているのでしょうか？

Mac OS Xで、Homebrewを使ってインストールしました。
なお、elispファイルは下記のディレクトリに格納されています。
/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-mac/emacs-25.1-z-mac-6.1/share/emacs/25.1/lisp/

Answer (score 2):

ヘルプ画面から、 C の関数へのリンクは、 `find-function-C-source-directory` 変数に、その emacs がコンパイルされたディレクトリを設定することによって、実現できます。

Homebrew の場合ですと、おそらく `~/Library/Caches/Homebrew/emacs-*` (`*` の部分はバージョン番号)にソースコードが存在するかもしれません。その場合は、 `(setq find-function-C-source-directory "~/Library/Caches/Homebrew/emacs-24.3/src")` (emacs のバージョンが 24.3 だと仮定しています)を `~/.emacs` などに追加します。

Answer (score 1):

emacs 内で C言語のソースコード(ヘッダ)を検索する場合、`etag` というコマンドでタグテーブルを作成し、`M-.` や `M-x find-tag` で関数を追跡していました。

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tags-Tables.html#Tags-Tables

Answer (score 0):

GitHubでミラーされているので、まずはそちらで眺めてみてはいかがでしょうか。
https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/src/window.c

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。最終手段としてgithubのミラーリングサイトを参照することも考えていたのですが、できればEmacs上で関数検索してソースコードを追っていきたいです。