# apt source で emacs のソースコードをダウンロードしたい

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, apt

[EmacsのソースコードをEmacsで関数検索しながら読みたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/33400/754) の回答を検証してみようと、手元の ubuntu にインストールされている emacs のソースコードを取得しようと考えました。

`apt source emacs` を用いると、やりたいことが実現できるのではないかと思い、このコマンドを実行したところ、以下のようなファイル群が手元のディレクトリに作成されました。

```
$ find .
.
./emacs-defaults_46.1.tar.xz
./emacs-defaults_46.1.dsc
./emacs-defaults-46.1
./emacs-defaults-46.1/debian
./emacs-defaults-46.1/debian/control
./emacs-defaults-46.1/debian/source
./emacs-defaults-46.1/debian/source/format
./emacs-defaults-46.1/debian/copyright
./emacs-defaults-46.1/debian/changelog
./emacs-defaults-46.1/debian/compat
./emacs-defaults-46.1/debian/rules
```

これは、たぶん自分のほしい、「emacsのソース群」ではなさそうだ、と思っています。

#### 質問

私の手順に間違いなどありますでしょうか。また、今回ダウンロードされたファイル群はいったい何者でしょうか。

#### 補足: `apt source emacs` した際のコンソール出力

```
$ apt source emacs

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
Picking 'emacs-defaults' as source package instead of 'emacs'
Need to get 2,582 B of source archives.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main emacs-defaults 46.1 (dsc) [1,446 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main emacs-defaults 46.1 (tar) [1,136 B]
gpgv: Signature made Thu 07 Aug 2014 05:03:23 PM UTC using RSA key ID 5A5A42F1
gpgv: Can't check signature: public key not found
dpkg-source: warning: failed to verify signature on ./emacs-defaults_46.1.dsc
dpkg-source: info: extracting emacs-defaults in emacs-defaults-46.1
dpkg-source: info: unpacking emacs-defaults_46.1.tar.xz
Fetched 2,582 B in 0s (2,853 B/s)
```

Comment: `apt show emacs` とすれば分かると思いますが、emacs package は meta package です。C のソースコードを取得するのであれば、`emacs24-bin-common` や `emacs25-bin-common` package の方になります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私がダウンロードしていたのは、 emacs の metapackage のソースでした。 [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages)とは、それ自身ではソフトウェアの実体を持たない、依存関係のみを持っているようなパッケージです。

実際、 `apt show emacs` を実行すると、次のような情報が出力されます。

```
(略)
Description: GNU Emacs editor (metapackage)
 GNU Emacs is the extensible self-documenting text editor.
 This is a metapackage that will always depend on the latest
 recommended Emacs release.
```

このときの、 依存対象は `Depends: emacs24 | emacs24-lucid | emacs24-nox` であって、実際にこのパッケージをインストールした際には、上記のパッケージのうちのどれか一つがインストールされることになります。手元の環境では `emacs24` がインストールされていたので、 `apt source emacs24` を実行した結果、 emacs のソースファイルを取得することができました。